# Multiple near with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following "query":

```
MySchema
    .where('address1.loc').near({
        center: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: user.address1.loc
        },
        maxDistance: 10 * 1000
    }).where('address2.loc').near({
        center: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: user.address2.loc
        },
        maxDistance: 10 * 1000
    })
    .exec(function(err, objects) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(objects);

        if(err) return eachCallback(err);

        return eachCallback();
    });
```

My schema has two addresses (one pickup- and one handover-address). So I have to use two "nears". But this doesn't seem to be possible:

`{ [MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Too many geoNear expressions] name: 'MongoError' }`

What are my alternatives?

**Update:**
I talked to some guys from MongoDB. Although my use case for this is valid, this doesn't seem to be possible out-of-the-box. So I'm looking for a "workaround". If you need details about the use case, let me know.

And here is how I defined the location inside my "addresses":

```
...
loc: {type: [Number], index: '2dsphere'},
...
```

Comment: Hi, did you define your `.loc` fields as GeoJSON?   And did you add `2dsphere` indexes?

Comment: See updated question. But it's not a problem with my schema. When using just one address it works fine. Seems to be a limitation of MongoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had encountered the same issue and error message. But I cannot remember exactly how I could overcome. I hope we can overcome your issue!
If your schema definition like the following, please try to the below solution;

```
loc : {
        'type': { type: String, default: 'Point' },
        coordinates: [Number]
    }
```

Could you check address.loc.coordinates stores as number on your collection?

### Alternate way

**Try to use `$geoWithin` operator**

I think you can change your questioning clauses like the following. You should use `$geoWithin` and `$centerSphere` instead of `$near` and `$maxDistance`. You've tried to find records that have `loc` fields in 10.000 meters proximity. `$centerSphere` indicates `radius`, it uses legacy coordinate values (only [longitude, latitude]) and it can used with `geoJSON` field and `2dsphere` index. And your `$centerSphere` definition must be `10/6371` for 10 km. ([tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/)).

If you use a second operator with `$near` operator it occurs a problem on [MongoDB side](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#behavior).

> You cannot combine the $near operator, which requires a special geospatial index, with a query operator or command that uses a different type of special index. For example you cannot combine $near with the $text query.

```
var r = 10/6371;
var area1 = { center: address1.loc.coordinates, radius: r, unique: true }
var area2 = { center: address2.loc.coordinates, radius: r, unique: true }

MySchema
    .where('address1.loc').
    .within()
    .circle(area1)
    .where('address2.loc').
    .within()
    .circle(area2)
    .exec(function(err, objects) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(objects);

        if(err) return eachCallback(err);

        return eachCallback();
    });
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Looks like it's working. I'm gonna test that now and will give you feedback asap. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Hi @mosquito87, Mongoose doesn't insert a second another operator when we use `where` operator second or more time. Would it be possible you've tried `$near` operator with another operator? If so I want to edit my answer to delete Mongoose part of response.

Comment: In order to convert to the radius unit, should we divide the distance by `6371` or `111.12`? I was trying to use `6371` but got an empty result but `111.12` worked fine for me.

Comment: Hi @LVarayut, I really don't understand that why 6371 didn't work for you. I've forgotten the subject but I don't familiar with 111.12 value. Sorry...

Comment: @user3765109 Just forget it, it's my bad. Your solution worked perfectly for me using `6371`.